# Scrapy code: text with UK pound sign causing problems when extracting prices from a site using a spider

Tags: python, web-crawler, scrapy, screen-scraping, utf

I'm using a Scrapy spider to try and extract prices from the following page: http://www.saxoprint.co.uk/shop/business-cards

In particular the element I am interested in scraping is: 
//*[@id="customerGrossValue"]

When I run my spider it finds the element it returns u' '. I'm suspecting this is to do with UTF encoding and is being caused by the fact that the "£" sign is not ASCII.

I am running Windows 7 and Python 2.7

I have done quite a bit of searching on this and have tried to encode to utf-8 but to no avail.

I'm sure this is probably something simple but it's very frustrating so any help would be gratefully received.

Thanks!

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*- 
import scrapy
from scrapy.selector import Selector
from scrapy.http import Request
from scrapy.spider import BaseSpider
from scrapy.selector import HtmlXPathSelector
from saxoprint.items import SaxoprintItem
from scrapy.contrib.linkextractors.sgml import SgmlLinkExtractor
from scrapy.contrib.loader import ItemLoader
from scrapy.contrib.exporter import XmlItemExporter


class saxoprintSpider(BaseSpider):
    name = "saxoprint"
    allowed_domains = ["saxoprint.co.uk"]
    start_urls = [
     "http://www.saxoprint.co.uk/shop/business-cards"
    ]

    def parse(self, response):
        selector_object = response.xpath('//div[starts-with(@class,"pricetableDIV")]')
        for select in selector_object:

            price_item = select.xpath('.//span[(@id="customerNetValue")]/text()').extract()[0].strip()
            print price_item #test the value

            item = SaxoprintItem(
                price=price_item
            yield item
```

Comment: Great - thanks! This worked for me. It helped me to resolve that I was not returning the text I needed by my spider. I have since used Selenium to get the content I need. Your answer helped a lot in getting me onto the right direction. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If I understand correctly, you want to transform a unicode string containing not only digits to a number. This should work:

```
>>> s = u'ę123'
>>> int("".join([c for c in s if c.isdigit()]))
123
```

You iterate through characters in the string creating a list of only those characters that are digits (`isdigit()`). After that you transform the list back to a string (`"".join(...)`), only to finally cast it to an integer (`int(...)`).